# No item in list in string Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv

I have a list of things I want to filter out of a csv, and I'm trying to figure out a pythonic way to do it.  EG, this is what I'm doing:

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outf:
    with open('input.csv', 'rbU') as inf:
         read = csv.reader(inf)
         outwriter = csv.writer(outf)
         notstrings = ['and', 'or', '&', 'is', 'a', 'the']
         for row in read:
             (if none of notstrings in row[3])
                 outwriter(row)
```

I don't know what to put in the parentheses (or if there's a better overall way to go about this).

Comment: You mean you want to exclude a row if column 4 contains any of those words?

Comment: What kind of values are there in `row[3]`? Is it a sentence? Is there punctuation? Should only whole words be matched?

Comment: No, just column 3.  Also, row 3 is *supposed* to be a name, but I'm slowly creating a list of filters to avoid non-names (better too zealous than not zealous enough).  However, I'm more using this to learn the best methods than to be specific to this one application.

Comment: I was counting from 1, `row[0]` is the 1st column, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to test each of the words in your list against a column:

```
if not any(w in row[3] for w in notstrings):
    # none of the strings are found, write the row
```

This will be true if *none* of those strings appear in `row[3]`. It'll match *substrings*, however, so `false-positive` would be a match for `'a' in 'false-positive` for example.

Put into context:

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outf:
    with open('input.csv', 'rbU') as inf:
        read = csv.reader(inf)
        outwriter = csv.writer(outf)
        notstrings = ['and', 'or', '&', 'is', 'a', 'the']
        for row in read:
            if not any(w in row[3] for w in notstrings):
                outwriter(row)
```

If you need to honour word boundaries then a regular expression is going to be a better idea here:

```
notstrings = re.compile(r'(?:\b(?:and|or|is|a|the)\b)|(?:\B&\B)')
if not notstrings.search(row[3]):
    # none of the words are found, write the row
```

I created a [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK1hD2/2) for the expression to demonstrate how it works. It has two branches:

- `\b(?:and|or|is|a|the)\b` - matches any of the words in the list provided they are at the start, end, or between non-word characters (punctuation, whitespace, etc.)
- `\B&\B` - matches the `&` character if at the start, end, or between non-word characters. You can't use `\b` here as `&` is itself not a word character.

Comment: how could I use \ba\b to avoid false positive for a?  Is r'\ba\b' sufficient?

Comment: @Xodarap777: that won't work for the `&` as it is not a word character. For the rest it'd be sufficient. You can make it one regular expression to do the test without `any()`, in one step: `r'\b(and|or|is|a|the)\b'`. I'll look into mixing in the `&` there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sets. In this code, I transform your list into a set. I transform your `row[3]` into a set of words and I check the intersection between the two sets. If there is not intersection, that means none of the words in notstrings are in `row[3]`.

Using sets, you make sure that you match only words and not parts of words.

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outf:
    with open('input.csv', 'rbU') as inf:
        read = csv.reader(inf)
        outwriter = csv.writer(outf)
        notstrings = set(['and', 'or', '&', 'is', 'a', 'the'])
        for row in read:
            if not notstrings.intersection(set(row[3].split(' '))):
                outwriter(row)
```

Comment: Does this method avoid the false positives of any()?

Comment: This requires that there are only spaces and words in `row[3]`; it won't work if punctuation is involved.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's correct. If there is punctuation, the string needs to be split by multiple delimiters or parsed with regex